# How can I merge 3 textbox values into a single Date to write into a dataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview, textbox, timespan

Im new to C# and I am making a program that saves different times. And I wonder how can I write out a single Date with three textBox strings (by typing in the value for day, month and year seperately) and how can I do the same for Time (write the hours and minutes).

```
int a = int.Parse(textBox_DDVzleta.Text);
int b = int.Parse(textBox_MMVzleta.Text);
int c = int.Parse(textbox_YYVzleta.Text);

DateTime Vzlet = new DateTime(a, b, c);
```

I tried converting it into a integer but it just doesnt work.

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you passes your parameters with wrong position.

You use `DateTime(year, month, day)` constructor but you pass them as `DateTime(day, month, year)` to this constructor.

Just change your parameter positions like;

```
DateTime Vzlet = new DateTime(c, b, a);
```

> how can I do the same for Time (write the hours and minutes).

If you mean `TimeSpan` with `Time`, you can use it's `TimeSpan(hour, minute, second)` constructor as well.

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(hour, minute, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a so called [DateTime Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x(v=vs.110).aspx) (MSDN Reference). You can initialize this with the given year, month and day integer and it creates for you the datetime object.

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2010, 8, 18);
```

In this case you could do

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(int.Parse(textBox_DDVzleta.Text), int.Parse(textBox_MMVzleta.Text), int.Parse(textbox_YYVzleta.Text));
```

See Screenshot below for the result.

[image]

**Update**

I have also tried your way with converting to int first.

```
int a = int.Parse("30");
int b = int.Parse("01");
int c = int.Parse("2016");

DateTime date2 = new DateTime(c, b, a); // new DateTime(year, month, day)
Console.WriteLine(date2.ToString());
```

the result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using string type variable and concatenation.
example:

```
string x = a.tostring()+b.tostring()+c.tostring();
```

for spaces between values You can write it as following.

```
string x = a.tostring() + " " + b.tostring() + " " + c.tostring();
```